# Regarding communication between Javascript publisher and Java/JMS API based consumer

Tags: javascript, java, jms, ibm-mq, amqp

Can I publish message using MQLight (https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/mq-light/) in Javascript & consume message in a Java consumer using JMS API from a Queue over an IBM MQ AMQP broker?

As I understand, MQLight is an AMQP based wire protocol and theoretically it can transmit a message to a queue. I plan to do a PoC to validate my assumption, but since it's a long drawn process, I would appreciate if somebody could share their experience with the same thing helping me, so that if it's a dead end I won't spend much time.

Comment: "..consume message in a Java producer using JMS API from a Queue over an IBM MQ AMQP broker?" Yes, you can use JMS API to consume messages in a queue independent of which broker you use. BTW, If the Java program consumes messages then it is a consumer not producer.

Comment: Check out "[MQ Light or other AMQP client submitting requests to a message-driven bean running in an application server and consuming responses from a reply topic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.amqp.doc/amqp_scen_clients_mdb.htm)" and "[MQ Light or other AMQP clients exchanging messages with IBM MQ applications](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.amqp.doc/amqp_scen_clients_msgs.htm)".  These show it is possible to do what you want to do.

Comment: You could either create a administrative subscription from a topic the AMQP client is publishing to a MQ queue and have the IBM MQ Classes for JMS app consume from the queue, or you could have the IBM MQ Classes for JMS app directly subscribe to the topic the AMQP client is publishing too.